# Migrating Libraries from Codeigniter to Laravel

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

I'm trying to migrate my app from code igniter to laravel. I have a lot of custom self written libraries that also need to be transferred over. In code igniter I simply put my Libs inside the app/libraries folder and I can load them in very easily. I can just do `$this->load->library('someclass');` and `$this->someclass->some_function();` and it works. Now I have been looking for ways to accomplish the same on laravel but I didn't manage to find anything. I have tried a lot of them but they didn't seem to work. Do you guys have any idea on how I can do this?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespacing is your answer. Put them all in a namespace, so open a script with `<?php namespace Library;` Add `app/libraries` to the autoload.classmap in your composer.json. Then after placing all your libraries in there, run `php composer.phar dump-autoload`. You'll then be able to access any library by just calling, for example`$class = new Library\someclass();`!

Comment: So I need to create a new instance for everything or can I also do Library\someclass() ?

Comment: That works too, just gave an example. Reference Libaray\someclass as the class name for any operations.